# LINQ - Aggregate and calculate several parameters

Tags: c#, linq, object

I have the following

```
List<Stock> _investments= new List<Stock>()
        {
            new Stock {id=msft, price =12, qty=20}
            new Stock {id=msft, price =53, qty=50}
            new Stock {id=csco, price =222, qty=20}
            new Stock {id=fb, price 40, qty=100}
        }
```

Given a symbol, say msft, I want to get the total investment and the charged price.
In the above case it would be

```
id=msft, qty=70, price = (12*20 + 53 *50)/70 = 41.29
```

How to do that in LINQ?
I can get the 12*20 + 53*50  that way:

```
var c = _investments.Where(i => i.ID == investmentName.ToUpper()).Sum(k => k.InitialPrice * k.Qty);
```

but how to inlcude the total qty in an efficent way

Answer (score 2):

Use `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
var result = _investments
   .Where(g => g.Key == "msft")
   .GroupBy(i => i.id)
   .Select(g => new{ id = g.Key,  qty = g.Sum(i => i.qty), grp = g })
   .Select(x => new
   {
       x.id,
       x.qty,
       price = Math.Round(x.grp.Sum(i => (decimal)i.price * i.qty) / x.qty, 2)
   });
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://ideone.com/BTstS4)</kbd>

Note that i have casted the price to `decimal` to prevent integer division (truncates decimal places). `Math.Round` is used to round the result on two decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to go seems:

```
var relevantInvestments = _investments
    .Where(i => i.ID == investmentName.ToUpper())
    .ToArray();

var totalQty = relevantInvestments.Sum(k => k.Qty);
var c = relevantInvestments.Sum(k => k.InitialPrice * k.Qty) / totalQty;
```

To iterate only once:

```
var c = _investments
    .Where(i => i.ID == investmentName.ToUpper())
    .Aggregate(
        new { Price = 0, TotalQty = 0 },
        (total, i) => new 
                      { 
                          Price = total.Price + i.InitialPrice * i.Qty,
                          TotalQty = total.TotalQty + i.Qty
                      },
        i => i.Price / i.TotalQty);
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way to include the calculated values could be to make a class for this. That way, you have clearly named and typed values without using anonymous types, and you ensure that the work of calculating it only happens once. For simplicity, I'm using `double`s everywhere here, and `string`s for the IDs, which may or may not match your types (`decimal` should probably be used for money amounts).

```
class StockGroup
{
    public List<Stock> Stocks { get; private set; }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public double TotalPrice { get; private set; }
    public double AveragePrice { get; private set; }
    public double Qty { get; private set; }

    public StockGroup(string id, IEnumerable<Stock> stocks)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Stocks = stocks.ToList();
        foreach (var stock in this.Stocks)
        {
            this.Qty += stock.Qty;
            this.TotalPrice += stock.Price * stock.Qty;
        }
        this.AveragePrice = this.TotalPrice / this.Qty;
    }
}

// use like
var groups =
         _investments.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => new StockGroup(x.Key, x));
```